# Sending data to multiple URL endpoint with PHP or Perl

Tags: networking

With "ClickBank", they have an Instant Notification Service. It can send data to two URL endpoints. If the other server doesn't respond, it tries again and again after varing time intervals until it gets a "200" response. I'm wondering if this could be "emulated" using Perl or PHP.

The reason being, other sites only allow ONE end point - which makes life difficult if data needs to be sent to two places! My original script creates a "dummy" script on the client's server that the INS originally pointed to, then did a fork. One child uses Curl to send data to my site, whilst another child send data to the original script on the server. That works ... if they have access to the other server, but not if sending the data to (say) "Stripe"

So this morn, I had the idea of running the fork on my site. My first idea was a cron job that checked a file for URL's that needed to be notified, and then to create forks / child processes to wait 5 ~10 seconds for the response. (No response, add to a text file to try again later). But then I reasoned that if I had 100 customers, and each wanted to relay the IPN information to five oother servers, that was (potentially) 500 child processes running concurrently.

Potentially, it could run faster if I didn't wait for the "200" response, but that is sort of half the battle.

So I'm curious to know if there is a more "efficient" way I could do it using Perl or PHP ... if at all. (I know nothing about "Sockets" and "TCP" etc, so be gentle with me it you suggest this route!) Even with my own virtual server, I think 500 concurrent childs would slow everything down. (I'm on a shared server) Even running 10 forks at a time, and waiting 10 seconds for response it would still take 50x 10 secs to complete the process. Don't think host would be too happy with that running every 15 mins!

Comment: My best guess is that "IPN" stands for "Instand Payment Notification", but I could be wrong this morn.

Comment: Do you think you should be writing payment handling systems when you've got limited programming skills? I suspect that you really need a highly available messaging queueing capability - which is a well defined architecture.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the term IPN was well known amoungst programmers. but your right. And to symcbean, NO I am not handling payments - I am handling the webhooks which are API endpoints sent out by the payment processors.

Comment: I have found an article on "Medium" which suggests PHP cURL to send out multiple requests asynchronously, and then use a foreach loop to await their responses.

https://medium.com/@imanilchaudhari/send-multiple-asynchronous-curl-requests-using-php-998acfce1622  Anil Chaudhari

Not checked, but it's a start